# Does NSNotificationCenter removeObserver: deregister a VC from receiving MemoryWarning Notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just stumbled about an issue in my app: I tested the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` calls to an `UIViewController` including the follow-up calls for `viewDidUnload`.

This used to work fine in older versions of my app, but was not working now within iPhone Simulator: 
`didReceiveMemoryWarning` was just not called any more.

This was caused by calling `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` in `viewWillDisappear` (self being the UIViewController) to unregister for some lifecycle notifications I did add in `viewDidAppear`.

That global `removeObserver:` call did not only remove my added notifications, but apparently also the system's UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification notification caused the UIViewController's `didReceiveMemoryWarning` being called.

Is this behaviour by design? I could not find a reference/document which was pointing out, that calling `removeObserver:` within a UIViewController breaks the standard memoryWarning handling.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.

This behavior doesn't surprise me at all. The implementation of UIViewController is opaque so there is no way to know for sure that it is registering instances for `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` with the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` action but that would certainly make sense.

As a general rule, it's bad practice to use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` anywhere but in `dealloc`. This is because, as you've discovered, there can be unpredictable side effects in superclass implementations. It's more predictable and easier to debug/maintain your code if you follow the convention of only unregistering for the specific notifications you registered for.

Comment: As an aside, I wish Apple provided a way to unregister certain *selectors*, since that's much less likely to go wrong (unless you've overridden a selector, in which case it's already gone wrong).

Comment: @tc I would assume, if Apple-Code registered for an event, the likelihood is high, that the class provides a matching method to override (as _didRecieveMemoryWarning_). Some hints in the docs would be nice though. Unregistering _selectors_ would make things even more controllable.

Answer (score 4):

`[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer]` unregisters `observer` for all notifications for which it had previously registered (including system notifications).
You can use `removeObserver:name:object:` method for unsubscribing from single notification.