# addObserver: name

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

I'm using an addObserver like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(notificationReceived:) name:nil object: nil];
```

Everything works well, but I thought it might be good form to remove the observer when I no longer needed it... I found that I needed to use this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"observerName" object:nil];
```

Problem is, when I change my addObserver line to include the name so that the removeObserver will know which observer to remove, the notifications no longer get called. This line is run but ignored when the name is added:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(notificationReceived:) name:@"observerName" object: nil];
```

I can set the name back to nil and it works again.
Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in the name?

Comment: instead of giving twice you may face typo, so use `const NSString *notificationName=@"observerName";` and use it in all the places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be mistaken as the what the parameters mean.

The `name:` tells the system which notifications you want to be informed about.

`self` is the actual observer, so when you `removeOberserver:self` you will stop to receive *any* notifications.

You should read the documentation carefully again as to which have which meaning:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1

For an example, see [How to create a class to send and receive events through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286347/how-to-create-a-class-to-send-and-receive-events-through-nsnotificationcenter-in)

Comment: Thanks - I had read in [another stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627001/does-nsnotificationcenter-removeobserver-deregister-a-vc-from-recieving-memoryw) that I shouldn't call removeObserver:self without the name: parameter.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that the name: is used to choose which system notification we want to listen for, it's much nicer now that I'm only getting the notification I specifically want and not EVERY notification. I can also use the notification name in the removeObserver:name:object: function and it works properly. So instead of @"myNotificationName" you need an actual notification like @"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" in the name: parameter of both addObserver and removeObserver